# JavaMail 1.4 always throws AssertionError when assertions are enabled (-ea)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, assertions

When using an older version of JavaMail, 1.4, with a JVM running with assertions-enabled `-ea`, JavaMail always throws an `AssertionError` on connection to an SMTP server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1578)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:251)
```

The `AssertionError` is completely unexpected, I would expect the connection to work, and it does work fine without JVM assertions-enabled.

Can anything be done to resolve this error short of giving-up running with assertions?

Comment: I have edited the question.  It does not seek advice on coding or debugging.  It has a clear problem statement (JavaMail throws `AssertionError`).  This question is about the behaviour of a particular version of a third-party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a newer or current JavaMail.  This looks like an old bug which has since been fixed in the JavaMail reference implementation, with the fix post version 1.4.

Reviewing [SMTPTransport source code](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java?rev=713) , it performs a lot of assertions checking that the code is holding the current monitor/lock on itself.  One of the methods was missing the synchronized keyword, making this untrue, resulting in an `AssertionError`, but only if assertions are explicitly enabled.  It looks like the method missing the synchronization block was fixed in [this revision](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/revision/344).

The simplest course of action is to either upgrade to a newer JavaMail, or disable assertions.

See also [JIRA knowledge base](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/java.lang.AssertionError+When+Sending+Mail+Via+SMTP).